# Import error cannot import name read_json

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

parser.py

```
import os
import json
import sys
def read_json()
...

def parser_json()
```

metadata.py

```
 from parser import read_json, parser_json
 ....
```

But I keep getting this error:

from parser import read_json, process_json
ImportError: cannot import name 'read_json'

Comment: `parser` is a particularly bad name, as python has a builtin `parser` module - its the python parser. Try a different name.

Comment: That worked immediately... thank you